# Javascript (ExtJS 4.1.1) TypeError: t is null

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs

I'm trying to display an extjs-4 tree, the backing store is filled with json from an ajax call (which appears to be successful) but the tree does not show. Instead I get an error:

```
TypeError: t is null    ext-all.js (line 38)
```

---

**Edit:** I'm now using `ext-dev.js` which gives the error:
`TypeError: el is null` at the line:

`el = el.dom || Ext.getDom(el);`

---

line 38 aside I was wondering if I have made any glaring errors in my javascript...

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.tree.*',
    'Ext.data.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.define('pools', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['text', 'id']
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'pools',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get_all',
            reader: 'json'
        }
    });

    store.load();

    // create the Tree
    var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
        viewConfig: {
            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
            }]
        },
        height: 350,
        width: 400,
        title: 'Directory Listing',
        renderTo: 'viewer',
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

The json object that successfully returns is:

```
{"text": ".", "children": [{"text": "pool1", "id": "pool1", "children": [{"text": "pool1/vol01", "leaf": "true", "id": "pool1/vol01"}]}, {"text": "pool5", "id": "pool5", "children": [{"text": "pool5/vol", "leaf": "true", "id": "pool5/vol"}, {"text": "pool5/vol2", "leaf": "true", "id": "pool5/vol2"}]}]}
```

A stack trace using google chrome reveals:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null ext-dev.js:20437
Ext.define.doInsert ext-dev.js:20437
Ext.define.append ext-dev.js:17115
Ext.define.render Renderable.js:783
Ext.define.constructor AbstractComponent.js:1126
Base.implement.callParent ext-dev.js:6271
Ext.define.constructor Component.js:336
Base.implement.callParent ext-dev.js:6271
Ext.define.constructor Panel.js:144
constructor ext-dev.js:7459
(anonymous function)
Ext.ClassManager.instantiate ext-dev.js:8199
(anonymous function) ext-dev.js:3015
(anonymous function) viewer.js:26 <----------- from my javascript above (var tree=...)
(anonymous function) ext-dev.js:14498
Ext.util.Event.Ext.extend.fire ext-dev.js:14658
Ext.apply.readyEvent.event.fire ext-dev.js:14901
Ext.apply.fireReadyEvent ext-dev.js:14999
Ext.apply.onDocumentReady ext-dev.js:15023
fn ext-dev.js:10056
Ext.apply.triggerReady ext-dev.js:10042
Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-dev.js:9540
Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-dev.js:9541
Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-dev.js:9541
Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-dev.js:9541
Ext.apply.refreshQueue ext-dev.js:9541
Ext.apply.onFileLoaded ext-dev.js:9947
(anonymous function) ext-dev.js:3001
onLoadFn
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What happens when you use `ext-dev.js` instead of `ext-all.js`? IMO you should be using the former, rather than the latter, to find problems at this stage.

Comment: `TypeError: el is null` at `el = el.dom || Ext.getDom(el);`

Comment: found the error! The div id had a different name between .js and .html. DOH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add HTML code below to Body of page :

```
<div id="viewer"></div>
```

Comment: this actually turned out to be my problem! I had made a typo in the div id!! My real fault however was using `ext-all.js` for development

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error `TypeError: t() is null` when migrating from javascript to typescript: I added *index.tsx* but forgot to delete the old *index.js*. The stack trace revealed that the old *index.js* was used.
The problem went away after deleting the old index.js.